# Fork one directory on github

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I have a project on github, which is a fork of a big project.
I created a plugin for that but they told me they will not include the plugin, I have to ship it separately, so now I want to fork the already forked project, but not everything, just the directory where I did that plugin. Is it possible?

*edit:*
Apparently on github i can't fork my own repository, so I think the answer's no.

Comment: Have a look at [Git Submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). That's indeed not a correct solution for your question, but could be a nice way of "bypassing" your problem for the future.

Comment: Well I had no idea they'd tell me to create my own project. I wanted my patches accepted.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `git filter-branch` to rewrite the whole history of your repository, just to keep (and move) your plugin. Doing so allows you to keep your plugin history.
Then use `git submodule` as https://stackoverflow.com/users/1967966/anh-nhan-nguyen suggested in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14895900/611560

Regards.

Comment: I tried using filter-branch and then it told me that my local copy was behind, said i needed to pull before i could push, and restored itself...

Answer (score 3):

#### Simply `git filter-branch` will do the job.

Clone the repository that contains the subfolder.

```
git clone https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY-NAME
```

To filter out the subfolder from the rest of the files in the repository, run git filter-branch, supplying this information:

- `FOLDER-NAME`: The folder within your project that you'd like to create a separate repository from.
- `BRANCH-NAME`: The default branch for your current project, for example, master or gh-pages.

.

```
cd REPOSITORY-NAME
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter FOLDER-NAME  BRANCH-NAME
```

Set up a new remote URL for your new repository using the existing remote name and the remote repository URL and push

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/NEW-REPOSITORY-NAME.git
git push -u origin BRANCH-NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the directory with the plugin in a separate GitHub repository. I assume it's `yourname/yourplugin`

Fork the big project (`yourname/bigproject` here), and add the plugin repository as a submodule.

```
git clone git@github.com/yourname/bigproject .
git submodule add git@github.com:yourname/yourplugin path/to/the/plugin
```

When updating / pulling, just run the following command:

```
git pull --recurse-submodules
git submodule update
```

I think for the first time you have to do `git submodule update --init` though. Could be my imagination.